# PHP and a file written by Java FileOutputStream

Tags: java, php

I have a text file that is written by Java FileOutputStream.

When i read that file using `file_get_contents`, then everything is on same line and there are no separators between different strings.
I need to know, how to read/parse that file so i have some kind on separators between strings

I'm using somethig like this, to save the file:

```
Stream stream = new Stream(30000, 30000);
stream.outOffset = 0;
stream.writeString("first string");
stream.writeString("second string");

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("file.txt");
out.write(stream.outBuffer, 0, stream.outOffset);
out.flush();
out.close();
out = null;
```

Comment: How does the file look if you read it with Notepad or some other plain editor ?

Comment: Please show an example of what the file looks like

Comment: `explode ( "\n" , file_get_contents(...) )`?

Comment: Please show an example of what the file looks like, not the Java code to create it

Comment: Gedit can't open it. It has some weird encoding. But i added my Java code to my question.

Comment: I know now that the separator is byte 0

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what that `Stream` thing in your code represents, but the usual approach to write `String` lines to a file is using a [`PrintWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html).

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("/file.txt"), "UTF-8"));
writer.println("first line");
writer.println("second line");
writer.close();
```

This way each line is separated by the platform default newline, which is the same as you obtain by `System.getProperty("line.separator")`. On Windows machines this is usually `\r\n`. In the PHP side, you can then just [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on that.

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` returns the content of the file as a string. There are no lines in a string.

Are you familiar with newlines?
See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)

So, what you are probably looking for is either reading your file line for line in PHP,
or reading it with `file_get_contents` like you did and then `explode`-ing it into lines (use "\n" as separator).

Comment: file_get_contents reads the contents of the file as a string, but that means it also reads new line characters. If you print the result of file_get_contents of a string that includes new line characters, then those characters will appear in the printed output.

Comment: Yes. He did not state anything on output though. It could even be he’s outputting as HTML, where newlines are pruned white-space so they will not be displayed by the Browser. Not enough detail there from the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

There is no indication in your code that you are writing a line separator to the output stream. You need to do something like this:

```
String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");

Stream stream = new Stream(30000, 30000);
stream.outOffset = 0;
stream.writeString("first string");
stream.writeString(nl);
stream.writeString("second string");
stream.writeString(nl);

FileOutputStream out = null;

try
{
    out = new FileOutputStream("file.txt");
    out.write(stream.outBuffer, 0, stream.outOffset);
    out.flush();
}
finally
{
    try
    {
        if (out != null)
            out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioex) { ; }
}
```

Using PHP, you can use the explode function to fill an array full of strings from the file you are reading in:

```
<?php

    $data = file_get_contents('file.txt');
    $lines = explode('\n', $data);

    foreach ($lines as $line)
    {
        echo $line;
    }

?>
```

Note that depending on your platform, you may need to put '\r\n' for the first explode parameter, or some of your lines may have carriage returns on the end of them.